# Magento - How Do I Get All The Invoices Of A Sales Order With A HTTP GET Request To The API?

Tags: magento, get, magento2

**Requirements:**

To obtain all the invoice information of a sales order, by using only the sales order `id`.

**Problem:**

Looking at the [Magento 2 API Documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/), I cannot see a method that allows a `HTTP` `GET` request. Also, when viewing the response for the sales order, I cannot see a reference to the invoice `id`. `/orders/{order_id}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to the [API documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/), and find "invoices".

The request should look something like this:

```
/V1/invoices
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][eq]
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][id]
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][invoice_id]
```

[image: Invoices Screen Grab]